# Determining power series for $\frac{3x^{2}-4x+9}{(x-1)^2(x+3)}$

Tags: polynomials, power-series

I'm looking for the power series for $f(x)=\frac{3x^{2}-4x+9}{(x-1)^2(x+3)}$

**My approach:** the given function is a combination of two problems. first i made some transformations, so the function looks easier.

$$\frac{3x^{2}-4x+9}{(x-1)^2(x+3)})=\frac{3x^{2}-4x+9}{x^3+x^2-5x+3}$$

Now i have two polynomials. i thought the Problem might be even easier, if thinking about the function as:

$$\frac{3x^{2}-4x+9}{x^3+x^2-5x+3)}= (3x^{2}-4x+9)\cdot \frac{1}{(x^3+x^2-5x+3)}$$

Assuming the power series of  $3x^{2}-4x+9$ is just $3x^{2}-4x+9$ itself. I hoped, i could find the power series by multiplying the series of the both easier functions.. yeah, i am stuck.

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\cdot x^{n}=(3x^{2}-4x+9)\cdot \ ...?... =$ Solution

Comment: Have you thought about the fact that (3x^2-4x+9) = (3x^2-4x+1+8) = (3x-1)(x-1)+8 ?

Comment: you mean i should form the Expression this way:  $\frac{3x^{2}-4x+9}{(x-1)^2(x+3)}=\frac{(3x-1)(x-1)+8}{x^3+x^2-5x+3}=\frac{2}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{3}{x+1}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the partial fraction decomposition:
$$
\frac{3x^{2}-4x+9}{(x-1)^2(x+3)}=
\frac{A}{1-x}+\frac{B}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{C}{1+\frac{1}{3}x}
$$
and sum up the series you get, which are known.

If you do the computation, you find $A=0$, $B=2$ and $C=1$, so

$$
\frac{3x^{2}-4x+9}{(x-1)^2(x+3)}=
\frac{2}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3}x}
$$

The development of $(1-x)^{-2}$ can be deduced from the fact that
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n
$$
so, by deriving, we get
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n\ge1}nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)x^n
$$

The power series for the other term is again easy:
$$
\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3}x}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n}x^n
$$
so your power series development is

$$
\frac{3x^{2}-4x+9}{(x-1)^2(x+3)}=
\sum_{n\ge0}\left(2n+2+\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n}\right)x^n
$$

Comment: $\frac{2}{(x‌​-1)^2}+\frac{3}{x+1}$ ?

Comment: @ToralfWestström No; you have $x+3$ in the denominator of the original fraction.

Comment: but where did you get the $1+\frac{1}{3}x$ from?

Comment: @ToralfWestström Just observe that $\frac{C}{1+x/3}=\frac{3C}{3+x}$; the form with $1+x/3$ makes it easier to write down the power series.

Comment: i still don't get it. how can i make partial fraction from the given function to this form?